# Tag synonym - all lotus tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

A tag search for `*lotus*` finds the following:

- [lotus](/questions/tagged/lotus)
- [lotus-notes](/questions/tagged/lotus-notes)
- [lotus-domino](/questions/tagged/lotus-domino)
- [lotusscript](/questions/tagged/lotusscript)
- [lotus-formula](/questions/tagged/lotus-formula)
- [lotus-sametime](/questions/tagged/lotus-sametime)
- [lotus-wcm](/questions/tagged/lotus-wcm)

The most popular, [lotus-notes](/questions/tagged/lotus-notes), has the following in it's wiki:

> Lotus-Notes-oriented questions on StackOverflow are infrequent enough that the single lotus-notes tag should encompass all Lotus Notes language topics, including LotusScript, the Notes formula language, the Notes C/C++ API, and the COM and Java interfaces.
>
> It is appropriate to also include specific language tags when asking questions about communicating with Lotus Notes from those languages, for example using .NET or VBA to send an email, or to pull data from SQL into Notes.

Given that all tags together have a total there are ~1,000 questions, the tags probably all be made synonyms of each other, with the main tag being [lotus-notes](/questions/tagged/lotus-notes).

Comment: *"Lotus-Notes-oriented questions on StackOverflow are infrequent enough that..."* This is the same kind of short-sighted thinking that ended up with my local "$1.25 Cleaners" charging me over $5.00 to dry clean a suit.

Comment: And if that were true, why couldn't we just use the [tag:lotus] tag? Is there any risk of people confusing it with [the flower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelumbo_nucifera)?

Comment: @TheEstablishment - *shrug* it's the one with the most questions, so it's the most intuitive, I guess. Beats me. It doesn't really matter either way.